# Using Solr with Meteor

Tags: node.js, web-applications, solr, meteor

I am working with Meteor JS and currently new in it. Since Meteor uses only Mongo DB, I need to integrate Solr with it for faster search access. Googled but to no avail. Can anyone please share with me some methods, links, or code snippets where I can use Solr with my Meteor project.

Answer (score 5):

Try with [Lunr](https://atmospherejs.com/lbee/lunr) package.
First install it on meteor

```
meteor add lbee:lunr
```

According to docs.

> A bit like Solr, but much smaller and not as bright.

[Here](http://lunrjs.com/example/) is the live demo, and [API](http://lunrjs.com/docs/)

Also you might look at [this](http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-way-to-implement-full-text-search-in-Meteor) conversation on Quora about Text-Search and [this](http://www.quora.com/Whats-the-best-way-to-handle-full-text-search-with-MongoDB) other too

PD: Example code on the Lunr Package info on Atmosphere

Comment: Hi! This just looks like Lunr Demo. I need integration with Meteor JS

Comment: to make it work with meteor just type the following 
`meteor add lbee:lunr`, already added to the answer.

Comment: @avishek gurung did you ended using lunr?

Comment: yes Finally I implemented Solr in Meteor. Didnt try Lunr. And Ethan, thanks a lot for ur help.

Comment: @avishekgurung could you please share how you implemented Solr in Meteor? maybe add it as your own answer to this question, so that people who come after you can find it useful? Thanks! :)

Comment: @avishekgurung Please do post some notes about your experience using Solr with Meteor. I'm going to be using it in a meteor app soon and would be very interested to hear your thoughts. Thanks!